# How would you jointly call elements and attributes on XML?

Tags: xml

So I'm writing some code doing something with XML format and I need a name with which to call both attributes and elements. I've been reading the W3C XML spec but they don't have the terminology for this or I couldn't find it.

The best I could come up with is:

```
 dataItemType = DataItemType.Element;
 dataItemType2 = DataItemType.Attribute;
```

or maybe

```
 nodeType = NodeType.Element;
 nodeType2 = NodeType.Attribute;
```

but neither seem properly representing the idea. I suppose nodes are only elements and "data item" seems too generic.

Any suggestions? Did anyone find something in the space where they name these somehow?

Comment: Why do you need to call two things that are fundamentally different by the same name?

Comment: I mean they are 2 elementary things on an XML. What if I want to store all names of attributes and values into a hashtable or something. Can I avoid having to call it `elementAndAttributeHashtable`? I find it weird that this terminology is lacking

Comment: @PaulCrovella This is exactly what I was looking for. I supposed node could be the proper name but I wasn't sure if I guessed the terminology